# An cookie to keep an user logged should be made of what?

Tags: php, security, cookies

I'm trying to follow this **rule**: *When user changes his password, he should log out of  all devices.*

That means I have to mix his password into cookie? Ok here is my code:

```
$hash = hash('sha512', $id.$email.$password);
$db->query("update users set cookie ='$hash' where email = '$email'");
setcookie("login", $hash, time() + (20 ^ 20), "/");
```

Ok what I'm doing is correct? Actually I'm asking this because I read somewhere:

> never put password into cookie.

Well if I want to follow sentence above, then my rule won't work. In fact I need a cookie based on the password which causes log-out when user changes his password.

Comment: Downvoter may you please tell me why?

Comment: Because you're not using `random_bytes()` to generate the token, I'd wager.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Why should I use `random_bytes()`?

Answer (score 1):

Thats what SESSIONS are for. In fact they are cookies but theres just a browser id saved in the cookie. The servers got a table wich contains the sessions of every user id. But an attacker could still copy the id but he cannot access the content of the session as it is stored on the server.

```
<?php session_start; $_SESSION["pass"]="test";?>
```

Ok the same goes to your hashing. A saved id could be copied by an attacker. Use tokens.
When the user logs in a random token is added into a database and stored into a session. If you want to kick out all users just delete these tokens. For extra security exchange the token sometimes. That makes it harder for an attacker because the token just works for a few minutes.